# post the result values in an array

Tags: php

I have used the following code to display the previous and after years of current year.

```
<?php
$year = date(Y);
$endyear = $year + 10;
$startyear = $year - 10;
for ($i = $startyear; $i <= $endyear; $i++)
{
    echo $i;
}
?>
```

I want to put the resulting values of `$i` in an array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for($i = $startyear; $i <= $endyear; $i++)
{
    $arr[] = $i;
}
```

check array using `print_r($arr);`

Answer (score 2):

Shorter solution

`$arr = range($startyear, $endyear);`

Comment: Remove the 1 at the end if you want it shorter :P `$arr = range($start, $end);`

Comment: @Anton thanks. (I also set default parameters in my projects)